# Laravel 4: Query builder retrieve join table data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

In Laravel, we could join 2 tables with this:

```
DB::table("users")->join('moreusers', 'users.id', '=', 'moreusers.user_id')->get();
```

And retrieve data with this:

```
$querydata[$i]->email
```

If both tables contain the same column name, how can I specifically retrieve it from first and second table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `select()` method:

```
DB::table("users")
    ->join('moreusers', 'users.id', '=', 'moreusers.user_id')
    ->select('users.email as user_email', 'moreusers.email as other_email')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But after I call `count()`, the `user_email` and `other_email` variable gone. I tried to avoid it by assign count on other variable and also via function, but it is still the same. How can I have those variable remains after `count()`? Thank you.

Comment: Do you use query builder count method or PHP built-in count function?

Comment: I think query builder count method overwrite your select part. So use PHP count function to get count of the records.